# Android, переход между активити

Tags: android, анимация, transition

Помогите, нашел вот такой переход. Очень понравился, хочу себе сделать, но не выходит. Помогите!
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Shared-Element-Activity-Transition
Видно, что там сделано на клик объекта из списка. Я сделал слушатель в адаптере, но что то не выходит. В чем проблема?? Дайте хоть какой то совет

```
    package com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta.Adapter;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ActivityOptions;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta.DetailLeader;
import com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta.Object.Leader;
import com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class LeaderAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener{
    private List<Leader> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;

    public LeaderAdapter(Context context, List<Leader> list){
        this.context = context;
        if (list != null)
            this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return list.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        if (view == null) {
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.leader, parent, false);
        }

        TextView lName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.leaderName);
        TextView lPosition = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.leaderPosition);
        TextView lWork = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.leaderWork);

        lName.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        lPosition.setText(list.get(position).getPosition());
        lWork.setText(list.get(position).getWork());
        view.setOnClickListener(this);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.e("samuliak","Create intent");
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, DetailLeader.class);
        Log.e("samuliak","Create transitionName");
        String transitionName = context.getString(R.string.transitionLeaderName);
        Log.e("samuliak","Create ActivityOptions");
        ActivityOptions transitionActivityOptions = ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, v, transitionName);
        Log.e("samuliak","Start activity");
        context.startActivity(intent, transitionActivityOptions.toBundle());
        Log.e("samuliak", "All good!");
    }
}
```

AndroidManifest

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta">

        <uses-permissio

n android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListAllLeadership"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_list_all_leadership"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
        <activity android:name=".DetailLeader"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

build.gradle

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


         }
        }
    }

        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
            compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
            compile 'org.apache.poi:poi:3.9'
            compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.7.2'
        }
```

Логи ошибки:

```
 03-15 12:46:39.404 1928-1928/com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
03-15 12:46:39.404 1928-1928/com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta, PID: 1928
                                                                      java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
                                                                          at com.hpk.pr131.hpk_beta.Adapter.LeaderAdapter.onClick(LeaderAdapter.java:72)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: На какой версии тестируете? Уверены, что активити не должна быть из библиотеки поддержки?

Comment: Тестирую на андроид 5.1 lollipop через дженимоунеш. Нет, в том то деле, что не должно. Это указывается между какими активити сделать перехеод. И что то не выходит( Помогите

Comment: Вот сюда вторым параметром должен Ваш imageView заходить ActivityOptions.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, v, transitionName)

Comment: Нет, не помогает. Поменял как сказали, но все равно ошибка. Сейчас прикреплю логкет

Answer (score 1):

Я делаю так:

```
    // Link to YourScreen
            btnLinkToScreen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            YourActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            finish();
        }
    });
```

А в вашем примере все как-то усложнено